# IO error for static file in appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

AppEngine throws the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/home/username/code/appname/csv/master.csv'
```

The relevant part of the script looks like this:

```
project_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
csv_data = csv.DictReader(open(project_dir+'master.csv','rU'))
```

The relevant part of the app.yaml looks like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /csv
  static_dir: csv
```

I get the same error when deleting the handler.

FYI: I do not get the IO error when putting the csv file in the top directory of my app. I need the handler because javascript on my website is sending a get request to the csv file and this does not work for the top-level directory (why?). I could have the csv in the top directory AND the csv directory at the same time but I think there could be a cleaner solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your app.yaml static handler to be application_readable.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig

application_readable
Optional. By default, files declared in static file handlers are uploaded as static data and are only served to end users, they cannot be read by an application.

Comment: now I get this error:
`Fatal error when loading application configuration:
Unexpected attribute 'application_readable' for object of type URLMap.`

Comment: Can you update your code examples?  I added this to a static handler and started up fine.

Comment: that would be `handlers:
- url: /csv
  static_dir: csv
  application_readable: true`

Comment: A simple working example.  Not sure if you need to tweak the static file path on appspot. This works with the dev_server, didn't deploy.  https://bitbucket.org/brianmichelich/ae_static_file/overview

Comment: cannot get it to work. thanks anyways! I will mark it as the correct answer as it theoretically should work as stated in the appengine docs and I cannot exclude the possibility that I have an outdated version of the sdk

Comment: try restarting dev server after updating app.yaml